# How to play chord with Firefox Audio Data API

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, audio

How can I play multiple notes at the same time to form a chord with the Firefox Audio Data API? I want to be able to fill a single array with 3 notes and play them all at the same time. Here is the code I have so far which works but the chord sounds terrible:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Create an Audio interface
var output = new Audio();

// Set up a mono channel at 44.1Khz
output.mozSetup( 1, 44100 );

// Create a sample buffer array
var samples = new Float32Array(22050); //22050 = 1 second

var g = 2* Math.PI * 391.995 / 44100;
var e = 2* Math.PI * 329.628 / 44100;
var c = 2* Math.PI * 261.626 / 44100;

// Fill the sample buffer array with values
for(var i=0; i<samples.length; i++){

    samples[i] = Math.sin(g * i) + Math.sin(e * i) + Math.sin(c * i);
    //samples[i] = Math.sin(c * i);
    //samples[i] = Math.sin(g * i);

}
</script>

<!-- Play the audio out -->
<button onclick="output.mozWriteAudio( samples );">Play</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If you fill the `samples[]` array with one note it sounds just fine. But it you fill it with multiple notes it doesn't sound anything like a chord. What do I have to change in my code to play a chord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just add your samples together you are going to get strong clipping. You need to scale down the output to the max value. Try this:

```
samples[i] = (Math.sin(g*i) + Math.sin(e*i) + Math.sin(c*i)) / 4;
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. What is the logic behind dividing by 4 for 3 notes? I am writing an app that can play x number of notes at the same time and I need to know what to divide the sum by. For example, if I played six notes at the same time would I divide by 7? Is there a formula you recommend I use for this?

Comment: The only reason I used 4 instead of 3 was to ease off the maximum a little. With 3 it would have *just* topped out when all three waves were in phase, but it usually sounds better to leave a little head room.